# Python GTK "Getting started" tutorial problem

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a problem with compiling a basic and really simple example of PyGTK usage listed on pygtk's website.

This is the first example from this site:
http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-GettingStarted.html

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example gtk.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

And after calling python gtk.py, i'm getting the following error:

> gtk
>   **main**
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "gtk.py", line 19, in 
>       base = Base()
>     File "gtk.py", line 11, in **init**
>       self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Window'

I've found an info somewhere that it shpuld be fixed by installing PyGTK from source. I did it but it changed nothing. The message is still the same.

I'm using ubuntu 10.10

Have you any ideas on what can be wrong ?
Thanks for any help!

Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, it seems like you might have named your script "gtk.py".

Which is a bad idea for what should be fairly obvious reasons!

Comment: Yes, it was named gtk.py but i've renamed it to it's original name base.py - the message is still there

Comment: @bajki and you definitely got rid of your old script that was called gtk.py? As in you actually "renamed" and didn't just "resave" with a different file name?

Comment: Hmm, wow, yes, there was an old file, i've just cloned it with 'cp'. I've removed it and now it's working. I don't understand why it was a problem but big thanks! :)

Comment: Import gtk was resolving to your py file.

Comment: ohhh right! i have no idea why i didn't noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: @bajki, No worries... I've done something akin to this before ;)
@Swiss, yes it certainly was.

Comment: 1. The script should also not be named 'cairo.py'. 2. Even after renaming, there might still be a *.pyc file the needs to be deleted.